# Positioning the image along the bottom of the div

Tags: html, css

I want to position the image such that it is placed in the center of div: #two, while the screen of the laptop is in div two and the lower body of laptop in div: #three. Below is the image of how I want it to look like but I'm unable to do so. [image]
This should also be responsive. If I readjust the window width and div: #one's height changes, the image should move along with it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}
#one{
    background-color: #293462;
    height: 20vw;
    display: grid;
    align-items: end;
}
#two{
    background-color: #216583;
    min-height: 40px;
    width: 100vw;
}
#three{
    background-color: #f76262;
    min-height: 100px;
}
h1{
    margin: 0;
}
ul{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
li{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
li:nth-child(3){
    grid-column: 4/5;
}
img{
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
    <div id="two">
        <ul>
            <li><h1>text</h1></li>
            <li><h1>text</h1></li>
            <li><h1>text</h1></li>
            <li><h1>text</h1></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="https://imgur.com/n8I8D6E.png" alt="laptop">
</div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

Comment: Why not make a `li` for the laptop image? Then you can align everything the way you are already.

Comment: @BryceHowitson but then I wont be able to position the laptop slightly lower than div#two. And the height of div#two will also increase if I add laptop in li

Comment: You can have a negative absolute position...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be over complicating this by using CSS Grid. I'd just use `flexbox` and `absolute positioning`.

Here's your code modified.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}
#one{
    background-color: #293462;
    height: 20vw;
}
#two{
    background-color: #216583;
}
#three{
    background-color: #f76262;
    min-height: 100px;
}
ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
li:nth-child(3){
   min-width: 30%;
    
}
img{
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:-15px;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two">
        <ul>
            <li><h1>text</h1></li>
            <li><h1>text</h1></li>
            <li><img src="https://imgur.com/n8I8D6E.png" alt="laptop"></li>
            <li><h1>text</h1></li>
            <li><h1>text</h1></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div id="three"></div>
```